# flutter_bluetooth_serial dependency can't connect to hc05

Tags: flutter, android-bluetooth, hc-05

`this is the function I use to connect:

```
 try { // Connect to the device. setState(() { isabs=true; });
 setState(() {
    loading=true;
  });
       connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(device.address);
   setState(() {
     isabs=false;

   });
  setState(() {
    loading=false;
  });
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, BluetoothControllerApp() as Route<Object?>);
  await connection?.close();
} catch (e) {
  print(connection?.isConnected);
  setState(() {
    isabs=false;

  });
 // Navigator.pop(context);
 // Navigator.push(context, DevicesList() as Route<Object?>);
  setState(() {
    loading=false;
  });
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Can\'t Connect'),
        content: Text('Bluetooth Device is not available'),
        actions: <Widget>[
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: IconButton(

                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
  },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right,size: 50,color: Colors.white,),

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
],
),
);
  print(e.toString());
}
```

and I get that in the terminal: I/BluetoothAdapter(14434): cancelDiscovery
I/BluetoothAdapter(14434): cancelDiscovery = false
D/BluetoothUtils(14434): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
I/BluetoothSocket(14434): connect() for device 414200 called by pid: 14434
W/BluetoothAdapter(14434): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
and the dialog can't connect
any help please

I don't know what to try I followed the flutter dependency documentation _ chatGpt yet still not working`